# Saving NSDictionary in Core Data using Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, nsdictionary

I did search many answers here that carry the same question title as mine, they're mostly in Obj-C and/or outdated. So please try to be patient...

I need to save an API response in Core Data for offline use.

Here is the response:

```
{
"data": [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "subtitle": "<p>Deutsches Ipsum Dolor deserunt dissentias Berlin et. Tollit argumentum ius an. Eichh\u00f6rnchen lobortis elaboraret per ne, nam Erbsenz\u00e4hler probatus pertinax, impetus eripuit aliquando Meerschweinchen sea. Diam scripserit no vis, Brezel meis suscipit ea. Eam ea Fernweh eleifend, ad blandit voluptatibus sed, Schnaps eius consul sanctus vix. Cu Aufschnitt legimus veritus vim<\/p><p>Deutsches Ipsum Dolor deserunt dissentias Berlin et. Tollit argumentum ius an. Eichh\u00f6rnchen lobortis elaboraret per ne, nam Erbsenz\u00e4hler probatus pertinax, impetus eripuit aliquando Meerschweinchen sea. Diam scripserit no vis, Brezel meis suscipit ea. Eam ea Fernweh eleifend, ad blandit voluptatibus sed, Schnaps eius consul sanctus vix. Cu Aufschnitt legimus veritus vim<\/p>",
    "text": "<p>Deutsches Ipsum Dolor deserunt dissentias Berlin et. Tollit argumentum ius an. Eichh\u00f6rnchen lobortis elaboraret per ne, nam Erbsenz\u00e4hler probatus pertinax, impetus eripuit aliquando Meerschweinchen sea. Diam scripserit no vis, Brezel meis suscipit ea. Eam ea Fernweh eleifend, ad blandit voluptatibus sed, Schnaps eius consul sanctus vix. Cu Aufschnitt legimus veritus vim<\/p><p>Deutsches Ipsum Dolor deserunt dissentias Berlin et. Tollit argumentum ius an. Eichh\u00f6rnchen lobortis elaboraret per ne, nam Erbsenz\u00e4hler probatus pertinax, impetus eripuit aliquando Meerschweinchen sea. Diam scripserit no vis, Brezel meis suscipit ea. Eam ea Fernweh eleifend, ad blandit voluptatibus sed, Schnaps eius consul sanctus vix. Cu Aufschnitt legimus veritus vim<\/p><p>Deutsches Ipsum Dolor deserunt dissentias Berlin et. Tollit argumentum ius an. Eichh\u00f6rnchen lobortis elaboraret per ne, nam Erbsenz\u00e4hler probatus pertinax, impetus eripuit aliquando Meerschweinchen sea. Diam scripserit no vis, Brezel meis suscipit ea. Eam ea Fernweh eleifend, ad blandit voluptatibus sed, Schnaps eius consul sanctus vix. Cu Aufschnitt legimus veritus vim<\/p>",
    "created_at": "2019-11-11 09:52:11",
    "updated_at": "2019-11-11 09:52:11",
    "deleted_at": null
}]
```

}

I've no problem viewing this response using WKWebKit this way:

```
class WebVC: UIViewController {

var selectedIndex = 0
var detailsArray = [NSDictionary]()

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupPage()
}

private func setupPage() {
    self.showAnimate()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
    showWebViewData()
}

func showWebViewData() {
    let title = "<h2>\(detailsArray[selectedIndex]["title"] ?? "")</h2>";
    let htmlstr = "\(title) \(detailsArray[selectedIndex]["subtitle"] ?? "") \(detailsArray[selectedIndex]["text"] ?? "")"
    print(htmlstr)
    let str = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira Sans Condensed' rel='stylesheet'> <style> body {font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';} .bg-white { background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6); border-radius:40px; padding: 20px; }html { padding: 10px;} h2 {font-size:40pt; color:#707070;} p{font-size:26pt; {font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;}.bold{font-weight:bold;}.italic{font-style: italic;}.oblique{font-style: oblique;}} strong{font-size:30pt}</style> </head> <body><div class='bg-white'>\(htmlstr) </div> </body> </html>"
    webView.loadHTMLString(str, baseURL: nil)
    webView.backgroundColor = .clear
    webView.isOpaque = false
}
```

But I'm having troubles saving the response in Core Data. 
I created an entity with one Transformable attribute to save the whole thing but it failed. I also tried to create three attributes: title, subtitle and text as Strings but it also failed.

```
    func saveInfoInCoreData(Emeregnecyinfos: [EmergencyInformation] ) {

    // Deletes Information Before Adding New One
    delete Info()
    for info in Emeregnecyinfos {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Info", in: Context)
        let information = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: PrivateContext)

        information.setValue(info.title, forKey: "title")
        information.setValue(info.subtitle, forKey: "subtitle")
        information.setValue(info.text, forKey: "text")

        do {
            try PrivateContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("Failed Saving Information!")
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated with code examples. Thanks!

Comment: "I am having trouble", what does that mean? What kind of trouble are you talking about, errors, crashes or what?